# Notepad++ - how to remove file prefixes?

Tags: notepad++, regex

In the following playlist, I want to basically delete all `digitdigit-` occurrences. For example, `02-Never` becomes `Never` and `04-Thriller` becomes `Thriller`. And I have other playlists that are over 300 songs long.  Any aid would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:242,"Never (Remix) - Heart"
D:\Music\Vinyl 45's\Heart\From the 'Heart' LP (1985)\02-Never (Remix).flac
#EXTINF:357,"Thriller - Michael Jackson"
D:\Music\Vinyl 33's\Michael Jackson\Thriller (1982)\04-Thriller.flac
#EXTINF:154,"Finger Poppin' Time - Hank Ballard and The Midnighters"
D:\Music\CD Greatest Hits\Amazing Early 60s Box (88 Hard To Find Hits) (2013)\16-Finger Poppin' Time.flac
#EXTINF:219,"Bad To the Bone - George Thorogood and The Destroyers"
D:\Music\CD Greatest Hits\Hard To Find 45's On CD\Volume 16 (More 80's Essentials and Beyond) (2016)\02-Bad To the Bone.flac
#EXTINF:390,"Shout - Tears for Fears"
D:\Music\CD Albums\Tears for Fears\Songs from The Big Chair (1985)\01-Shout.flac
#EXTINF:222,"Celebration - Kool and The Gang"
D:\Music\CD Greatest Hits\Billboard Top Hits (1980-1984) (1992)\20-Celebration.flac
#EXTINF:232,"The Look - Roxette"
D:\Music\Vinyl 45's\Roxette\From the 'Look Sharp!' LP (1988)\01-The Look.flac
#EXTINF:224,"Come Together - Aerosmith"
D:\Music\Vinyl 45's\Aerosmith\From the 'Sgt Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band Soundtrack' (1978)\01-Come Together.flac
#EXTINF:235,"(We Want) The Same Thing - Belinda Carlisle"
D:\Music\CD Albums\Belinda Carlisle\Runaway Horses (1989)\06-(We Want) the Same Thing.flac
#EXTINF:125,"Return To Sender - Elvis Presley"
D:\Music\Vinyl 45's\Elvis Presley\From the 'Girls, Girls, Girls' Motion Picture Soundtrack LP (1962)\01-Return To Sender.flac
#EXTINF:392,"Hotel California - Eagles"
D:\Music\CD Singles\Eagles\01-Hotel California.flac
#EXTINF:329,"In the Air Tonight - Phil Collins"
D:\Music\CD Albums\Phil Collins\_ Hits (1998)\15-In the Air Tonight.flac
#EXTINF:261,"The Reflex - Duran Duran"
D:\Music\CD Greatest Hits\Rock and Roll Relix-The 80's (1998)\49-The Reflex.flac
#EXTINF:163,"Alley Oop - The Hollywood Argyles"
D:\Music\CD Greatest Hits\A Child's Celebration of Rock 'N Roll (1996)\07-Alley Oop.flac
#EXTINF:211,"Crazy In the Night - Kim Carnes"
D:\Music\Vinyl 33's\Kim Carnes\Barking At Airplanes (1985)\01-Crazy In the Night.flac
#EXTINF:224,"Rebel Yell - Billy Idol"
D:\Music\CD Greatest Hits\Now That's What I Call the 80's-Volume 2 (2009)\17-Rebel Yell.flac
#EXTINF:177,"It's Still Rock and Roll To Me - Billy Joel"
D:\Music\CD Albums\Billy Joel\The Complete Hits Collection (1997)\15-It's Still Rock and Roll To Me.flac
#EXTINF:223,"People Are People - Depeche Mode"
D:\Music\Vinyl 45's\Depeche Mode\From the 'People Are People' LP (1984)\01-People Are People.flac
#EXTINF:196,"Stray Cat Strut - Stray Cats"
D:\Music\CD Greatest Hits\Billboard Top Hits (1980-1984) (1992)\33-Stray Cat Strut.flac
#EXTINF:154,"Rockin' Robin - Bobby Day"
D:\Music\CD Greatest Hits\A Child's Celebration of Rock 'N Roll (1996)\06-Rockin' Robin.flac
#EXTINF:157,"Workin' for A Livin' - Huey Lewis and The News"
D:\Music\Vinyl 33's\Huey Lewis and The News\Picture This (1982)\05-Workin' For A Livin'.flac
#EXTINF:248,"One Night In Bangkok - Murray Head"
D:\Music\Vinyl 45's\Murray Head\From the 'Chess' LP (1984)\01-One Night In Bangkok.flac
#EXTINF:248,"Walk of Life - Dire Straits"
D:\Music\CD Albums\Dire Straits\Money for Nothing (1988)\08-Walk of Life.flac
#EXTINF:214,"We Are Family - Sister Sledge"
D:\Music\Vinyl 45's\Sister Sledge\From the 'We Are Family' LP (1979)\01-We Are Family.flac
#EXTINF:359,"All You Zombies - Hooters"
D:\Music\CD Albums\Hooters\Nervous Night (1985)\03-All You Zombies.flac
#EXTINF:218,"Tribal Dance - 2 Unlimited"
D:\Music\CD Greatest Hits\Greatest Sports Rock and Jams (Volume 4) (1999)\15-Tribal Dance.flac
#EXTINF:213,"Shake It Up - The Cars"
D:\Music\CD Albums\The Cars\Shake It Up (1981)\02-Shake It Up.flac
#EXTINF:239,"Invincible - Pat Benatar"
D:\Music\Vinyl 45's\Pat Benatar\From the 'The Legend of Billie Jean Soundtrack' LP (1985)\01-Invincible.flac
#EXTINF:133,"Purple People Eater - Sheb Wooley"
D:\Music\CD Greatest Hits\A Child's Celebration of Rock 'N Roll (1996)\10-Purple People Eater.flac
#EXTINF:187,"Ivory Tower - Limahl"
D:\Music\Vinyl 45's\Limahl\From the 'Never Ending Story Soundtrack' LP (1984)\02-Ivory Tower.flac
#EXTINF:223,"Down Under - Men At Work"
D:\Music\CD Greatest Hits\Billboard Top Hits (1980-1984) (1992)\31-Down Under.flac
#EXTINF:160,"The Lion Sleeps Tonight - The Tokens"
D:\Music\CD Greatest Hits\Best of 50's and 60's (2010)\08-The Lion Sleeps Tonight.flac
#EXTINF:284,"Y.M.C.A. - Village People"
D:\Music\Vinyl 33's\Village People\Crusin' (1978)\01-YMCA.flac
#EXTINF:179,"Bad, Bad Leroy Brown - Jim Croce"
D:\Music\CD Greatest Hits\Billboard (Number 1 Hits of The 70's) (2002)\04-Bad, Bad Leroy Brown.flac
#EXTINF:141,"Witch Doctor - David Seville"
D:\Music\CD Greatest Hits\Hard To Find Jukebox Classics\Hard To Find Jukebox Classics (1958 - More Pop Gold) (2009)\15-Witch Doctor.flac
#EXTINF:244,"Don't Bring Me Down - Electric Light Orchestra"
D:\Music\Vinyl 45's\Electric Light Orchestra\From the 'Discovery' LP (1979)\01-Don't Bring Me Down.flac
#EXTINF:180,"Orange Flip - Book of Love"
D:\Music\CD Albums\Book of Love\Candy Carol (1991)\11-Orange Flip.flac
#EXTINF:256,"Heart of Stone - Cher"
D:\Music\CD Albums\Cher\Heart of Stone (1989)\04-Heart of Stone.flac
#EXTINF:265,"Dream On - Aerosmith"
D:\Music\Vinyl 45's\Aerosmith\From the 'Aerosmith' LP (1973)\01-Dream On.flac
#EXTINF:149,"Does Your Chewing Gum Lose Its Flavor (On the Bedpost Overnight) - Lonnie Donegan and His Skiffle Group"
D:\Music\CD Greatest Hits\Amazing Early 60s Box (88 Hard To Find Hits) (2013)\58-Does Your Chewing Gum Lose It's Flavor (On the Bedpost Overnight).flac
#EXTINF:252,"Everybody Wants To Rule the World - Tears for Fears"
D:\Music\CD Albums\Tears for Fears\Songs from The Big Chair (1985)\03-Everybody Wants To Rule the World.flac
#EXTINF:192,"You Spin Me Round (Like A Record) - Dead or Alive"
D:\Music\Vinyl 45's\Dead or Alive\From the 'Youthquake' LP (1984)\01-You Spin Me Round (Like A Record).flac
#EXTINF:217,"We're Not Gonna Take It - Twisted Sister"
D:\Music\CD Greatest Hits\Greatest Sports Rock and Jams (Volume 4) (1999)\16-We're Not Gonna Take It.flac
#EXTINF:225,"Some Like It Hot (Extended Mix) - The Power Station"
D:\Music\Vinyl 45's\The Power Station\From the 'The Power Station' LP (1985)\01-Some Like It Hot (Extended Mix).flac
#EXTINF:142,"Itsy Bitsy Teenie Weenie Yellow Polka Dot Bikini - Brian Hyland"
D:\Music\Vinyl 45's\Brian Hyland\From the 'The Bashful Blond' LP (1960)\01-Itsy Bitsy Teenie Weenie Yellow Polka Dot Bikini.flac
#EXTINF:236,"Girls Just Want To Have Fun - Cyndi Lauper"
D:\Music\CD Albums\Cyndi Lauper\She's So Unusual (1983)\02-Girls Just Want To Have Fun.flac
#EXTINF:255,"A Horse with No Name - America"
D:\Music\Vinyl 33's\America\A Horse with No Name (1971)\05-A Horse with No Name.flac
#EXTINF:226,"Good Times Roll - The Cars"
D:\Music\CD Albums\The Cars\The Cars (1978)\01-Good Times Roll.flac
#EXTINF:259,"Polkas On 45 - ''Weird Al'' Yankovic"
D:\Music\CD Albums\Weird Al Yankovic\In 3-D (1984)\06-Polkas on 45.flac
#EXTINF:204,"Pass the Dutchie - Musical Youth"
D:\Music\CD Greatest Hits\Hard To Find 45's On CD\Volume 15 (80's Essentials and Beyond) (2016)\14-Pass the Dutchie.flac
#EXTINF:224,"(Keep Feeling) Fascination - The Human League"
D:\Music\CD Singles\The Human League\Fascination (1983)\01-(Keep Feeling) Fascination.flac
#EXTINF:343,"Radio Ga Ga - Queen"
D:\Music\CD Albums\Queen\Greatest Hits I and II (1992)\20-Radio Ga Ga.flac
#EXTINF:238,"The Final Countdown - Europe"
D:\Music\Vinyl 45's\Europe\From the 'The Final Countdown' LP (1986)\01-The Final Countdown.flac
#EXTINF:217,"Sweet Dreams (Are Made of This) - Eurythmics"
D:\Music\Vinyl 33's\Eurythmics\Sweet Dreams (Are Made of This) (1983)\06-Sweet Dreams (Are Made of This).flac
#EXTINF:229,"Heart of Glass - Blondie"
D:\Music\CD Greatest Hits\Now That's What I Call 70s\Heart of Glass.flac
#EXTINF:202,"Who Can It Be Now - Men At Work"
D:\Music\CD Greatest Hits\Billboard Top Hits (1980-1984) (1992)\25-Who Can It Be Now.flac
#EXTINF:204,"Never Ending Story - Limahl"
D:\Music\Vinyl 45's\Limahl\From the 'Never Ending Story Soundtrack' LP (1984)\01-Never Ending Story.flac
#EXTINF:225,"Oliver (Voices On the Radio) - Kim Carnes"
D:\Music\Vinyl 33's\Kim Carnes\Barking At Airplanes (1985)\10-Oliver (Voices On the Radio).flac
#EXTINF:122,"We Will Rock You - Queen"
D:\Music\CD Albums\Queen\Greatest Hits I and II (1992)\16-We Will Rock You.flac
#EXTINF:337,"Piano Man - Billy Joel"
D:\Music\CD Albums\Billy Joel\The Complete Hits Collection (1997)\01-Piano Man.flac
```

I found somewhere that `\*\d{2}` should have worked for what I want except it didn't.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help.  All options worked except -\d\d or -\d{2}. This one worked to well by erasing all the - .  The other two worked flawlessly.  I guess because all were .flac files.  Thank you all again for your help.

Comment: if any of the solutions helped, you should mark a chosen answer with the tick.

Answer (score 0):

For finding `-{digit}{digit}` use regular expression `-\d\d` (or `-\d{2}`).

Answer (score 0):

To accurately and reliably eliminate all the prefixes and only them (nothing else), assuming all files have `.flac` extension, you could use:

```
\\\d{2}-(.*?\.flac)$
```

Replace with:

```
\\$1
```

Breakdown:

- `\\` - backslash
- `\d{2}-` - followed by 2 digits and `-`
- `(.*?\.flac)` - and `.flac` extension preceded by anything matched non-greedily, captured into group number 1
- `$` - end of line

Then we replace with `\\` backslash and the 1st group (`$1`).

Answer (score 0):

- Find what: `^.+\K\d{2}-(?!.+\d{2})`
- Replace with: Leaveempty
- Search mode: `Regular expression`
- Enable `Wrap around`
- Press <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

**Explaination**

> - `^.+` matches any character from the start of a line asmany times as possible
> - `\K` forgets everything that have been matched up to this point
> - `\d{2}-` matches 2 digits followed by a dash
> - `(?!.+\d{2})`: Negative Lookahead. What follows the current position must not be followed by many characters followed by 2 digits and a dash

This allows to remove only the 2 digits followed in by the dash on the filenames and not folder names (see line 13).

**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]